# Getting array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array on register_post_type

Tags: custom-post-types

I am after taking over a website and checking the debug file for issues, one of the issues showing is: `array_merge(): Argument #2`.
After disabling the plugins/themes I found the issue is the register_post_type, if I remove that the messages stop appearing in the debug file.

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
function create_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'member',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => _x( 'Members', 'Members', 'text_domain' ),
                'singular_name' => _x( 'Member', 'Member', 'text_domain' ),
            ),
            'menu_position' => '6',
            'public' => true,
            'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'author'),
            'has_archive' => true,
            'capabilities' => 'remove_users',
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'member'),
        )
    );
}
```

The code above does add the post type, but I am unsure where the array_merge() error is coming from.

Comment: Can you post the full message? It should contain the line number and file it appeared in which would be useful ( even if it's not helpful that's still useful to know )

Comment: If you look at https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type, you will see that `capabilities` is expecting an array. If you place `remove_users` in an array do you still receive the error?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that **capabilities** argument should be an array and should be written like this:

```
'capabilities' => array('remove_users'),
```

instead of this:

```
'capabilities' => 'remove_users',
```

because capabilities argument always accepts array of values, even if it's single value.